# reducing Visual studio program size

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, window, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual studio community 2015 to program in C++. The program itself is **pretty bulky (+7go)**, and hard drive space is very limited on my ultrabook. Since I am using VS for **C++ exclusively** I'd like to remove unnecessary tools and feature (everything not related to C++), but going into program file\VS2015, and deleting the 'java' folder seems to be a bad idea. Any way to make it more **lightweight** ??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would go into Add/Remove Programs, find VS, choose Change, then in the VS installer choose Modify, and then customize the installed features to remove everything you don't want.

Unfortunately, VS' minimum install is around 4GB, and that's without C++, so you probably won't save a lot this way.